# How to toggle div visibility using radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project in which I have to toggle the visibility of a `<div>`.

I've got the following code:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="1"> Personal
<input type="radio" name="type" value="2"> Business

<div class="business-fields">
    <input type="text" name="company-name">
    <input type="text" name="vat-number">
</div>
```

I would like to togle the business-fields div. So, if none of the radio buttons, or the 'personal' radio button is selected: The div should be hidden. If the 'business' radio button is selected, I want it to show.

Currently, I am using this code:

```
$("input[name='type']").click(function() {
    var status = $(this).val();
    if (status == 2) {
        $(".business-fields").show();
    } else {
        $(".business-fields").hide();
    }
});
```

However, I was wondering if I can do this using the .toggle() function.

Comment: why not just use `.toggle()` then instead of show() and hide()?

Comment: @WeSt That'd work only if OP modified the code to use the `change` event.

Comment: for me.. the show() hide() is the best way then .toggle() because when you reselect personal it shows the textboxes..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd suggest using the `change` event, and supplying a Boolean switch to the `toggle()` method, which will show the jQuery collection of elements if the switch evaluates to `true`, and hide them if it evaluates to `false`:

```js
// select the relevant <input> elements, and using on() to bind a change event-handler:
$('input[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
  // this, in the anonymous function, refers to the changed-<input>:
  // select the element(s) you want to show/hide:
  $('.business-fields')
      // pass a Boolean to the method, if the numeric-value of the changed-<input>
      // is exactly equal to 2 and that <input> is checked, the .business-fields
      // will be shown:
      .toggle(+this.value === 2 && this.checked);
// trigger the change event, to show/hide the .business-fields element(s) on
// page-load:
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="1">Personal</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="2">Business</label>

<div class="business-fields">
  <input type="text" name="company-name">
  <input type="text" name="vat-number">
</div>
```

Incidentally, note I've also wrapped the associated text, to indicate the radio-button's purpose, inside of a `<label>` element to directly associate that text with the `<input>`, so clicking the text checks the `<input>` automatically.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 19):

I usually tend not to use JS if possible, therefore here comes a HTML+CSS way approach.

```css
.bussines-type .business-fields {
 display: none;
}

.bussines-type input[value="2"]:checked ~ .business-fields {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bussines-type">
 <input id="bt1" type="radio" name="type" value="1">
        <label for="bt1"> Personal</label>
 <input id="bt2" type="radio" name="type" value="2">
        <label for="bt2"> Business</label>

 <div class="business-fields">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Company name" name="company-name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Vat number" name="vat-number">
 </div>
</div>
```

The `~` stands for any siblings, that are after the element we defined before the `~` sign.

Answer (score 4):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhLwa1nt/5/)

Try this one

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="1" checked ="true"> Personal
<input type="radio" name="type" value="2"> Business

<div class="business-fields">
    <input type="text" name="company-name">
    <input type="text" name="vat-number">
</div>

.business-fields{
    display: none;
}



    $("input[name='type']").change(function() {
        $(".business-fields").toggle();
});
```

Comment: toggle is not good option for this: http://jsfiddle.net/jhLwa1nt/3/ first check to personal then you know the result is not what OP wanted

Answer (score 2):

You may use like this:

```
$("input[name='type']").change(function() {
    var status = $(this).val();
    if (status != 2) {
        $(".business-fields").hide();
    } else {
        $(".business-fields").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

.show and .hide are pretty slow. 
https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/564443848613847040

It's better to toggle a css class on and off with javascript. Set the css of the class to {visibility: hidden} or {display: none}

Answer (score 1):

use the below code

```
<script>
$(function(){
$(":radio[value=1]").click(function(){
    var isVisible = $( ".business-fields" ).is( ":visible" );
    if(isVisible==true)
        $('.business-fields').toggle();
});

$(":radio[value=2]").click(function(){
    var isVisible = $( ".business-fields" ).is( ":visible" );
    if(isVisible==false)
        $('.business-fields').toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

AND HTML is-

```
<input name="type" type="radio" value="1" >Personal
<input type="radio" name="type" value="2" checked="checked"> Business

<div class="business-fields">
    <input type="text" name="company-name">
    <input type="text" name="vat-number">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a more elegant solution, It's a bit more readable in my opinion, and and as @Ollie_W points out it might be more performant that toggle (show/hide).

```js
$('input[name="type"]').on('change', function(event) {
  var radioButton = $(event.currentTarget),
      isBusiness = radioButton.val() === 'business' && radioButton.prop('checked');
  $('.business-fields').toggleClass('hidden', !isBusiness);
}).change();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="personal">Personal</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="type" value="business">Business</label>

<div class="business-fields hidden">
  <input type="text" name="company-name">
  <input type="text" name="vat-number">
</div>
```